# How i can get data XML into store then into Tree list in Sencha Extjs?

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs

Anyone here who can help me i just only want to get data into store first then into treelist in Sencha Extjs but i dont know anything because i am a newbie in Sencha so far I use this code that is given below:

XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>
  <expanded>true</expanded>
  <children>
     <element>
        <text>Home</text>
     </element>
     <element>
        <children>
           <element>
              <leaf>true</leaf>
              <text>Messages</text>
           </element>
           <element>
              <leaf>true</leaf>
              <text>Music</text>
           </element>
        <element>
              <leaf>true</leaf>
              <text>Video</text>
           </element>
        </children>
        <text>Users</text>
     </element>
     <element>
        <text>setting</text>
     </element>
     <element>
        <children>
           <element>
              <leaf>true</leaf>
              <text>University</text>
          </element>
         </children>
        </element>
  </children>
```

Main.js code:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'treelist',      
    reference: 'treelist',
    expanderOnly: false, 
    listeners:{
        selectionchange :'treeNodeSelect' 
    },
    bind: '{navItems}',
}],
```

My Modal Data where store is located:

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.tree.TreeListModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.tree-liststore',
    fields: ['expanded', 'children', 'leaf', 'text'],
    data: {
        name: 'AppName',
    },
    stores: {
        navItems: {
            type: 'tree',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : '/classic/resources/test.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'children',
                    rootProperty: 'root'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thing on your XML structure:

1. You did not close the first `<root>` tag.
2. It would be wise to mark all nodes with `<leaf>true</leaf>` or `<leaf>false</leaf>`.
3. Your last Element has `children` but it has not text and it's not marked as `<leaf>false</leaf>`, so it would break the Tree Structure as it would have no node to contain the children.

Your XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <expanded>true</expanded>
    <children>
        <element>
            <text>Home</text>
            <leaf>true</leaf>
        </element>
        <element>
            <text>Users</text>
            <leaf>false</leaf>
            <children>
                <element>
                    <leaf>true</leaf>
                    <text>Messages</text>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <leaf>true</leaf>
                    <text>Music</text>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <leaf>true</leaf>
                    <text>Video</text>
                </element>
            </children>
        </element>
        <element>
            <text>Setting</text>
            <leaf>true</leaf>
        </element>
        <element>
            <text>Some Name Here</text>
            <leaf>false</leaf>
            <children>
                <element>
                    <leaf>true</leaf>
                    <text>University</text>
                </element>
            </children>
        </element>
    </children>
</root>
```

Also your xml reader does not need a `rootProperty` since it's `root` but you want only the first element related to it's parent to be considered a record, so your `record` should be: `> element`.

```
stores: {
    navItems: {
        type: 'tree',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'test.xml',
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: '> element'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23pv

Comment: i have a question this code works for me thanks and i also learn some concepts but i could not understand what u exactly mean by  "record: '> element' " why this bascially used for

Comment: Basically this means that your whole tree is already loaded in the that structure and every time you expand a record it won't try to load more records from the server.

Comment: hy @Guilherme can u also help me over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542658/how-to-load-url-from-xml-into-modal-in-sencha-extjs